# Raw pointer deferencing : strange Undefined Behavior allowed

Tags: rust

I'm playing with UnsafeCell to understand its behavior and I came to this code.

It's totally a UB, but I'm not able to explain why it compiles.

```rust
use std::cell::UnsafeCell;

fn main() {
    let cell = UnsafeCell::new(0);
    unsafe {

        let ptr1 = &mut *cell.get();
        let ptr2 = &mut *cell.get();
        *cell.get() += 1;
        *ptr1 += 1;
        *ptr2 += 1;
        dbg!(*cell.get());
    }
    dbg!(cell.into_inner());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a9a216314b5939c19f1c9764df6b3b58)

Comment: In short, UB does not mean your code won't compile. UB means **anything can happen**. Or as we call it, _nasal demons_ flying on your computer.

Comment: Of course you really should test your unsafe code under Miri, which rightfully rejects this code.

Comment: Ok but why this trigger a compile error
```rust
unsafe {
    let mut a = 12;
    let ref_a_mut = &mut a;
    let ref_a = &a;
    dbg!(ref_a_mut);
}
```
but not the above code ?

Comment: Because `unsafe` does not turn off the borrow checker, code with references will still work (or not) as usual. You only gain the right to play with raw pointers in addition, which do not have those restrictions.

Comment: so why taking two mutable reference in row on dereferenced *mut i32 doesn't give the same compile error ?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: The both example the one in my main question  and the code in the comment.

Comment: Because `UnsafeCell::get()` returns a raw pointer, so the borrow checker does not stop you.

Comment: I think I've found the root cause :)
https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/fifth-stacked-borrows.html#unsafe-stacked-borrows
and how to detect it

cargo miri run 

and I have the right bad error ^^

Comment: With `UnsafeCell` you're telling the compiler, "trust me, I got this, I'll manually uphold the guarantees you rely on for optimizations". One of the things you promised to uphold is to **not** do what you've done, calling `cell.get()` twice to create two mutable references to the same data. The point of `UnsafeCell` is to build safe abstractions that will uphold these guarantees through the virtue of restricted public API. `RefCell` is one example, using a single-threaded run-time check. `Mutex` is another, using thread-safe synchronization primitives. `Cell` and atomics are further examples.